# scala syntax understanding _* and type*

Tags: scala

I am having some difficulty in understanding this syntax:

```
(as: List[A]) =>    val h = insert(e, as: _*)}
```

and

```
def insert(h: H, as: A*): H = as.foldLeft(h)((hh, a) => insert(a, hh))
```

What do `_*` and `A*` mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def insert(h: H, as: A*): H = as.foldLeft(h)((hh, a) => insert(a, hh))
```

A* represents a vararg : you can supply as many As as you wish to the method

```
(as: List[A]) =>    val h = insert(e, as: _*)}
```

in this case a Sequences is converted to a vararg parameter ( a single list is converted into n single arguments having the type of A).

sometimes this is necessary, imho it doesnt change too much on the conceptual level (as you still can invoke fold , map etc  on both)

Answer (score 2):

`A*` is an argument define as a vararg, it's equivalent to `A...` in Java.

Exemple :

```
scala> def f(i: Int*) = i.length
f: (i: Int*)Int

scala> f(1,2,3)
res50: Int = 3
```

`:_*` is a transformer that allow to transform a param of type List into a vararg.

Exemple :

```
scala> f(List(1,2,3):_*)
res51: Int = 3
```